# Struggling with rails_admin multiple HABTM associations to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-admin

I'm looked all over Google, the Rails_Admin dox, etc and can't find an answer.

I have a model agency:

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :kids
```

And the kids model:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :agencies
    attr_accessible :agency_ids
```

In Rails_Admin, I access the agencies with this code:

```
config.model Kid do
    edit do
      field :agencies
    end
end
```

However, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to have an association to the same model in a different field. Something like:

```
config.model Kid do
    edit do
      field :agencies
      field :agencies_previous      
    end
end
```

where agencies_previous and agencies would reference the same agencies model.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is something like https://github.com/benedikt/mongoid-tree where you can reference a self model, its that what you need?